# Pandas keeps returning: "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame"

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am trying to adjust a dataframe by appending columns and changing values but get the well known warning:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

I've changed the code but keep getting the error. Am I doing it correctly and do I need to suppress the warning (if so, how can I do it on the specific line)?

The code:

```
def append_columns(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """Create additional columns based on existing information in DataFrame"""

    for col in TIMEWINDOWS:
        df.loc[:, col + "_time"] = df[col].dt.time  # warning here

    df["da_datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["da_time"], format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S").dt.tz_convert(config.TIME_ZONE)  # warning here

    df["da_time"] = (
        df["da_datetime"] - df["da_datetime"].dt.normalize()  # warning here
    )

    df["ud"] = pd.to_datetime(df["psb_time"], format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ").dt.dayofweek  # warning here
    df["ud"] = df["ud"].astype(int)  # warning here

    df["cd"] = df["ud"]  # warning here
    df.loc[df["psb_time"].dt.hour < 6, "cd"] -= 1
    df["cd"] %= 7  # warning here
    df["cd"] = df["cd"].astype(int)  # warning here

    return df

if __name__ == "__main__":
    df = pd.read_csv(...)
    df = df.pipe(...).pipe(append_columns).pipe(...)
```

On all of the lines I've tried replacing df[col] with df.loc[:, col] (the preferred method according to: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy) but I keep getting the warning.

Am I doing it correctly?
If so: can/do I need to supress these warnings on a per line basis?
Does it matter? (I'm overwriting anyways)

I've obviously read:

- https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
- [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)

and I think I understand but can't get rid of these warnings..

Answer (score 0):

The use of `.pipe()` caused these warnings. Removing it and (although less beautiful) replacing it would simple function calls solved the issue.